# Retrofit 2 - Retrofit.builder.build() method's working

Tags: android, http, retrofit2, okhttp

I read on Wikipedia that starting from HTTP/1.1, a connection can be reused for more than one request. So, does this line of code opens a single HTTP connection with base URL through

```
mBuider.build().create(API.class);
```

and then uses this connection for multiple subsequent requests made to the API endpoints or a new HTTP connection is established every time a new API endpoint is hit.

Calling the APIs

```
RestClient.getClient().getHomeData(mapHomeData).enqueue(new Callback<Example>().... 

RestClient.getClient().getUserData(mapUserData).enqueue(new Callback<Example>()....
```

RestClient class

```
public class RestClient {

private static API REST_API;


public static API getClient()
{
    if(REST_API==null)
    {
        createClient();
    }
    return REST_API;
}



private static void createClient()
{
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Retrofit.Builder mBuider=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient);

    REST_API=mBuider.build().create(API.class);
    }
}
```

API class

```
public interface API
{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.HOME_URL)
    Call <Example> getHomeData(@FieldMap HashMap<String,String> map);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.INDEX_URL)
    Call <Example> getIndexData(@FieldMap HashMap<String,String> map);
}
```

What exactly is

```
mBuider.build().create(API.class);
```

doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Both, Retrofit and OkHttp, are Open Source and well documented.

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere what I am asking. I searched a lot.